# showing emoji in pdf or excel

Tags: java, excel, pdf, itext

I have the data containing emoji in database. I want to display in the generated document such as pdf or in excel format.

I am using spring boot application. Please suggest any java library for generating either PDF or excel which supports emoji.

Comment: If your emoji is a Unicode character and you use a Unicode font that contains these emojis, then iText 7 already supports this out of the box. If your emoji is an image, then iText 7 also supports this out of the box.

Comment: Thanks, let me try implementing

Comment: Normally, you should try implementing first. That way you can present the people of SO with a concrete piece of code that doesn't work.

Comment: Doesnt know the way of implementing is the question. Next step is that only ..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iText supports this. Assuming

- your emoji is a unicode character
- you use a font that contains the correct glyph for this unicode character

Best way to test this is to try it.

This is how to get started with iText:

https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/installing-itext-7

And this is a small code-snippet that adds text to a document with different fonts:

```
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
Document document = new Document(pdf);

PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.TIMES_ROMAN);
PdfFont bold = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.TIMES_BOLD);
Text title =
    new Text("The Strange Case of Dr. Jekyll and Mr. Hyde").setFont(bold);
Text author = new Text("Robert Louis Stevenson").setFont(font);
Paragraph p = new Paragraph().add(title).add(" by ").add(author);

document.add(p);
document.close();
```

For more information check out the tutorials.
https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-1