# Adding UNICODE emoticon on pdf with itext

Tags: java, unicode, itext, itext7

I have some problem adding unicode emoticon on pdf created with itext pdf. I tried with this and itextpdf core 5.5.13

```
public class MathSymbols { 
public static final String DEST = "EXAMPLE.pdf";
public static final String FONT = "/res/fonts/arialuni.ttf";
public static String TEXT ;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    File file = new File(DEST);
    TEXT = "this "+Character.toChars(0x1F600)+" string \uD83D\uDE00 contains \ud83d\ude00 special \u2609 characters like this  \u2208, \u2229, \u2211, \u222b, \u2206";
    new MathSymbols().createPdf(DEST);

}

public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.open();
   BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(FONT, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
    Font f = new Font(bf,12);
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph(TEXT, f);
    document.add(p);
    document.close();
}}
```

I have the same proble on itextpdf 7.x with this snippet

```
public class Main {

public static final String DEST = "example.pdf";

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(DEST);
    new Main().createPdf(DEST);
}

public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException {
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
    Document document = new Document(pdf);
    PdfFont f = PdfFontFactory.createFont("/resources/arialuni.ttf", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H,true);
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph("H\u2082SO\u2074 1 \uD83D\uDE00 contains \ud83d\ude00 spe \u2702 cial \u2609 characters like this  \u2208, \u2229, \u2211, \u222b, \u2206").setFont(f).setFontSize(10);
    document.add(p);
    document.close();
}}
```

I tried with different fonts and different way in java like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48339194/showing-emoji-in-pdf-or-excel).
But I only obtaing a withe space, or a square, in the pdf and no emoticon

Comment: arialuni doesn't have any emoticons.

Comment: I tried many, can you suggest any font with emoticons?

Comment: The main problem: most font formats (and font design) doesn't allow multiple colour on the characters, so you will find not many fonts, and possibly they will not work with pdf (or many pdf readers). Put emoticons as tiny figures.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, for me is enough to have a black and wite for standard emoticon like this: ☺.